# Almost disjoint functions of size $2^{\omega_1}$ in $\omega^{\omega_1}$

Tags: set-theory

If we assume CH, it could be shown that there exists $2^{\omega_1}$ almost disjoint subsets of $\omega_1$. I'm wondering under CH if it's possible to show that there exists a family of almost disjoint functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$ of size $2^{\omega_1}$. Note 2 functions $f$ and $g$ are almost disjoint in $\omega_1$ if $|\{\alpha<\omega_1: f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)\}|<\omega_1$.

Comment: Under CH, or generally? Also note that $2^{\omega_1}\subseteq\omega^{\omega_1}$

Comment: "Almost disjoint"... that doesn't sound very well-defined now!

Comment: @Noldorin: Even if it may not sound so, it [is a technical concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_disjoint_sets) with a concrete definition.

Comment: So which definition of "small" are you using?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Under CH. Yes, but the problem is the family must contain almost disjoint functions.

Comment: @Noldorin: Cardinality is strictly less than the given cardinal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Also, just to nitpick, you mean functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$ (you miss the subscript on the second one), right? :)

Comment: @Noldorin: No, I mean functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$. They are not injective.

Comment: Anyway this seems pretty certainly true, but I'd need to formalise it properly. Will see if I can get around to it later.

Comment: Oh, my bad. So $\omega = \omega_0$ simply...

Answer (score 2):

It is consistent that there is no such family: If the non stationary ideal over $\omega_1$ is $\omega_2$-saturated, then there cannot be an almost disjoint family of functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$ of size $\omega_2$. Probably some forcing will give the other direction too.

From Jing Zhang's remark below, it follows that there is such a family in $L$.

Comment: Indeed, the existence of $\omega_2$ almost disjoint functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega$ is equivalent to the existence of $\omega_1$-Kurepa tree, which is independent of axioms of set theory (even with CH I think).